# Minor changes in a beamer presentation

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, titles

I have something i can't figure out.
1-How can I put the logo after the title in the first slide.
2-How can I remove the 1 and 2 in \inst{1}
3-How can I fill everything in the second slide (which is the first after the title)

```
\documentclass{beamer}

%\setbeamercolor{titlelike}{parent=structure,bg=cyan} %background color
%\setbeamercolor{titlelike}{parent=structure,fg=blue} %colore titoli
%\setbeamercolor{titlelike}{parent=structure,fg=yellow,bg=cyan} %colore e background in un comando

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepgflibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,quotes,angles} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16} 
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots} 
\usetikzlibrary{calc} 


\usepackage{xcolor} 
\definecolor{cobalt}{rgb}{0.0, 0.28, 0.67} 
\setbeamercolor{titlelike}{parent=structure,fg=cobalt} 


\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepgflibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,quotes,angles} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16} 
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots} 
\usetikzlibrary{calc} %rido

\setbeamercolor{itemize item}{fg=cobalt} % all frames will have cobalt bullets

\setbeamersize{text margin left=5mm,text margin right=5mm} %margini

%\usebackgroundtemplate{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{logo.jpeg}}
\title{\textbf{title }}
\author{name}

\institute[VFU] % (optional)
{
  \inst{1}%
  thesis\\
  uni
  \and
  \inst{2}%
  prof1\\
  pro2
}

\date[VLC 2013] % (optional)
{Lmarch}

\titlegraphic{\includegraphics[height=1.5cm]{logo.jpeg}}

\begin{document}

\maketitle


\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Title}

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    
    
      \draw [thick] (0,4)--(2,4)--(2,5.5)--(4,5)--(4,4)--(7,4)--(7,5.5)--(9.5,5.5)--(9.5,4);
      \draw [thick] (0,3)--(2,3)--(2,1.5)--(4,2)--(4,3)--(7,3)--(7,1.5)--(9.5,1.5)--(9.5,3);
      
      %Valvola CCV
      %\draw [thick] (4.5,4)--(5.5,3);
      %\draw [thick] (4.5,3)--(5.5,4);
      %\draw [thick] (4.5,4)--(4.5,3);
      %\draw [thick] (5.5,4)--(5.5,3);
      
      %Valvola Throttle
      %Valvola Throttle
      \draw [thick] (9.3,4)--(9.7,3);
      \draw [thick] (9.3,3)--(9.7,4);
      \draw [thick] (9.3,3)--(9.7,3);
      \draw [thick] (9.3,4)--(9.7,4);
      
      %Scritte
      \node[text width=3cm] at (3.5,1) {Compressore};
      \node[text width=3cm] at (9,1) {Plenum};
      %\node[text width=3cm] at (6,2.5) {CCV};
      \node[text width=3cm] at (11.5,2.5) {Throttle};
      
      
      \draw [->] (-0.5,3.2)--(0.5,3.2);
      \draw [->] (10,3.2)--(11,3.2);
      
      \node[text width=3cm] at (1.5,3.6) {$\phi$};
      \node[text width=3cm] at (4,4.5) {$\Psi_c(\phi)$};
      %\node[text width=3cm] at (6,4.5) {$\Psi_v(\phi)$};
      \node[text width=3cm] at (9.5,5) {$\psi$};
      \node[text width=3cm] at (11.5,3.6) {$\Phi(\psi)$};
      
    \end{tikzpicture}
    %\caption{\textit{Modello di Greitzer con CCV}}
  %\label{fig:modello_Greitzer_CCV}
\end{figure}


\begin{columns}

\column{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{equation}
\nonumber 
\begin{cases}
\dot{\phi}=B(\Psi_c(\phi)-\psi)\\
\dot{\psi}=\frac{1}{B}\left(\phi-\Phi_T(\psi)\right)
\end{cases}
\label{eq:modello_adimensionalizzato}
\end{equation}

\column{0.5\textwidth}

\begin{eqnarray}
\nonumber \Phi_T(\psi)=(\gamma_T\sqrt{\psi})\\
%\label{eq:phi}
\nonumber B=\frac{U}{2\omega_HL_c}\\
%\label{eq:psi}
\nonumber \omega_H=a_0\sqrt{\frac{A_c}{V_pL_c}}\\
\nonumber \gamma_T=Asin\left[\omega t\right]+b
\end{eqnarray}

\end{columns}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I recommend breaking down your problem into several questions (one question for each problem).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I have correctly captured all your questions.

1. Logo after the presentation title.
2. Remove upper numbers 1 and 2 in \inst{}
3. Fill (background color in the first slide (?)).

To fit the equations I used a `\small` font size and put four columns in the last array to fit  and align the equations.

[image: x]

[image: y]

This is the code. Marked with `<<<<<` added, changed or commented.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

%\setbeamercolor{titlelike}{parent=structure,bg=cyan} %background color
%\setbeamercolor{titlelike}{parent=structure,fg=blue} %colore titoli
%\setbeamercolor{titlelike}{parent=structure,fg=yellow,bg=cyan} %colore e background in un comando


%%% duplicated <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
%%\usepackage{tikz}
%%\usepgflibrary{arrows.meta}
%%\usetikzlibrary{calc,quotes,angles} 
%%\usepackage{pgfplots}
%%\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16} 
%%\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots} 
%%\usetikzlibrary{calc} 

\usepackage{xcolor} 
\definecolor{cobalt}{rgb}{0.0, 0.28, 0.67} 
%\setbeamercolor{titlelike}{parent=structure,fg=cobalt,bg=violet!50}    

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepgflibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,quotes,angles} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16} 
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots} 
 %\usetikzlibrary{calc} %rido <<<<<<<<<<<<<<

\setbeamercolor{itemize item}{fg=cobalt} % all frames will have cobalt bullets

\setbeamersize{text margin left=5mm,text margin right=5mm} %margini

%\usebackgroundtemplate{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{logo.jpeg}}
\title{\textbf{Presentation title } \\
     \vspace{30pt}
      \includegraphics[height=50pt]{example-grid-100x100pt}}%<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< changed
\author{name}

\institute[VFU] % (optional)
{%
%  \inst{1}% <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
  thesis\\
  uni
  \and
%  \inst{2}% <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
  prof1\\
  pro2
}

\date[VLC 2013] % (optional)
{Lmarch}

%\titlegraphic{\includegraphics[height=1.5cm]{example-grid-100x100pt}} %<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< 

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=violet!20} %<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< added
\setbeamercolor{titlelike}{parent=structure,fg=cobalt,bg=violet!50} %<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< added
\begin{frame}

\frametitle{Title first slide} %<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< changed

%\begin{figure}[h]%<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
%\centering%<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\small %<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< added
    \begin{tikzpicture}    
      \draw [thick] (0,4)--(2,4)--(2,5.5)--(4,5)--(4,4)--(7,4)--(7,5.5)--(9.5,5.5)--(9.5,4);
      \draw [thick] (0,3)--(2,3)--(2,1.5)--(4,2)--(4,3)--(7,3)--(7,1.5)--(9.5,1.5)--(9.5,3);      
      %Valvola CCV
      %\draw [thick] (4.5,4)--(5.5,3);
      %\draw [thick] (4.5,3)--(5.5,4);
      %\draw [thick] (4.5,4)--(4.5,3);
      %\draw [thick] (5.5,4)--(5.5,3);      
      %Valvola Throttle
      %Valvola Throttle
      \draw [thick] (9.3,4)--(9.7,3);
      \draw [thick] (9.3,3)--(9.7,4);
      \draw [thick] (9.3,3)--(9.7,3);
      \draw [thick] (9.3,4)--(9.7,4);      
      %Scritte
      \node[text width=3cm] at (3.5,1) {Compressore};
      \node[text width=3cm] at (9,1) {Plenum};
      %\node[text width=3cm] at (6,2.5) {CCV};
      \node[text width=3cm] at (11.5,2.5) {Throttle};
       \draw [->] (-0.5,3.2)--(0.5,3.2);
      \draw [->] (10,3.2)--(11,3.2);      
      \node[text width=3cm] at (1.5,3.6) {$\phi$};
      \node[text width=3cm] at (4,4.5) {$\Psi_c(\phi)$};
      %\node[text width=3cm] at (6,4.5) {$\Psi_v(\phi)$};
      \node[text width=3cm] at (9.5,5) {$\psi$};
      \node[text width=3cm] at (11.5,3.6) {$\Phi(\psi)$};      
    \end{tikzpicture}
    %\caption{\textit{Modello di Greitzer con CCV}}
  %\label{fig:modello_Greitzer_CCV}
%\end{figure}
\begin{columns}
\column{0.4\textwidth}%<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< changed 
\begin{equation}
    \nonumber 
    \begin{cases}
    \dot{\phi}=B(\Psi_c(\phi)-\psi)\\
    \dot{\psi}=\frac{1}{B}\left(\phi-\Phi_T(\psi)\right)
    \end{cases}
    \label{eq:modello_adimensionalizzato}
\end{equation}
\column{0.6\textwidth}%<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< changed 
\begin{align} %<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< changed to four columns to fit and align
    \nonumber \Phi_T(\psi)  &=(\gamma_T\sqrt{\psi})         & \nonumber B       &=\frac{U}{2\omega_HL_c}\\
    %\label{eq:phi}
    %\label{eq:psi}
    \nonumber \omega_H      &=a_0\sqrt{\frac{A_c}{V_pL_c}}   &\nonumber \gamma_T&=Asin\left[\omega t\right]+b\\
\end{align}
\end{columns}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: that's great, you even answered to a question I was about to make. super-thank you!